# Hiding Apps for power saving iphone 5s

Tags: iphone

On my iphone 5 I could make apps "disappear" by double clicking on the home button and then temporarily remove the ones in regular use by holding finger on them until the shook then cancelling by pressing the cross.This preserved battery power. On the iphone 5s this system doesn't work. Anyone have an answer?

Comment: By the way, as a side note on battery power, here is an interesting question/answer on keeping apps closed: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75582/is-it-good-to-keep-apps-closed-on-ios-devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You double-tap the home button as usual. The method of killing apps is different, though - just swipe the image of the app's screen up to kill it. This is a very nice feature as you can see what you are doing in an app before you zap it.

Comment: ...and it's nice that you can close three apps at a time (three fingers, swipe up).